# How to play Movieclip while making everything else hidden?

Tags: actionscript-3

How do i make it so when a movieclip is played by using .play() everything else on screen is hidden?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of ways to do this, depending on how you have your code laid out.  You can move the MovieClip to the top of the main display list and access everything else calling otherItem.visible = false;

Or just put a blank background behind the movieclip so it covers everything.  Provide some more insight into what you're doing and you'll get a less generic answer.